# Question in save image to folder from listview for vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Dim path As String = "c:\Mahesh" & TextBox1.Text
If Not Directory.Exists(path) Then

    Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
    '    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To ImageList1.Images.Count - 1

        FileCopy(ImageList1.Image.FromFile(path))
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(path))

    Next
Else
    MsgBox("خطأ")
End If
```

Comment: `ImageList1.Images(i).Save(.....)`

Answer (score 0):

You can save every image object with the [Image.Save method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).
In this case, you have to write something similar to this:

```
Private sub SavePNGFromImageList1(imgIndex as integer, path as String)
    ImageList1.Images(imgIndex).Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End sub
```

You can use different image formats (see [ImageFormat class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0))